# Google App Engine - Upgrading from App Engine Helper

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I would like to remove dependencies on the old-style App Engine Helper for Django in my Python-based App-Engine application . At the same time, I would like to upgrade to Python2.7 and Django1.4. I have a few questions about the upgrade process:

1) The new App Engine SDK (Version 1.7.4) states that Django is fully supported. Does this mean that neither the App Engine Helper nor the Django-norel will be required in order for Django to function on the App Engine?

2) Assuming that the answer to my previous question is that no external patches/helpers are required, I am having trouble finding an example App Engine/Django application based on the new SDK. Do you know where I could find a Django/AppEngine example that does not rely on external patches/helpers? (this will give me a known good starting point, which I can then port my existing code into).

3) Currently my database models inherit from BaseModel which was provided in the App Engine Helper. In order to not break my website, what should these models inherit from given the BaseModel will no longer exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django 1.4 with CloudSQL.

If you're using the HRD, you'd want to use django-nonrel (the successor to App Engine Helper).
While django-nonrel works, the documentation is a bit lacking at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at the django-nonrel documentation for an example configuration, and to see if there will be any issues with respect to updating the database models.

Comment: django-nonrel's models are the same as Django's - though there's a limitation on the types of queries that actually work.